# Are Magento Object propertyNames that are prefixed by "_" different from ones that aren't?

Tags: php-7, magento2.2.7, documentation

what does this tell me ? Is there a place in the devdoc's I wasn't able to find or is this a convention I don't know about?
thanx for your help... [image]

Comment: they are the same it's just a difference in coding standards

Comment: the one without prefix, is the standard used by Magento 2 versions

Comment: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 follows the [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#42-properties) coding standard, which states:

4.2

> Property names SHOULD NOT be prefixed with a single underscore to indicate protected or private visibility.

4.3

> Method names SHOULD NOT be prefixed with a single underscore to indicate protected or private visibility.

Comment: so the prefixed ones are public ?

Comment: the prefixed ones are the one used in Magento 1, which follows PSR-1, in the future it will not be used since Magento 2 and so on is using a PSR-2 coding standard

Comment: so the prefix doesn't really mean if the property is public or private or protected